# Getting HTML tag text by right-clicking on it - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created a PHP file that reads a directory and prints the files inside. The file names are written in a 'p' tag. Is it possible to get the text of the tag by right-clicking on it?

PHP Code

'''

```
<?php
 $dir = "../dashboard/uploads/";
 $content = scandir($dir);

 foreach($content as $file) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      echo "
      <div style='margin-left: 40%'>
          <div style='display: flex;'>
             <a href='../dashboard/uploads/$file' style='display: block; font-family: Open Sans; text-decoration: none; margin-bottom: 10px;' target='_blank'><p>$file</p><a>
            <form action='delete.php' method='get' style='text-align: left;'>
               <a href='delete.php?file=$file' type='submit' style='margin-left: 10px; text-align: right; color: red;'><p>Remove $file</p></a>
            </form>
         </div>
     </div>
  "; 
  
  }
} 

?>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.querySelector('a p').addEventListener("contextmenu", (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(ev.target.textContent);
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, unfortunately your code doesn't work but it helped me to find the correct code.

document.querySelectorAll('a p').forEach(p=>p.addEventListener("contextmenu", (evnt)=> {
        evnt.preventDefault();
        console.log(evnt.target.textContent);
      }));